# How to save strings in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I made a new xcode project using the master detail core data template. By default, it saves the date and makes that the title of each cell in the table. I tried changing it so It displays a string instead but it crashes every time.

I changed this

```
[newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

to this

```
[newManagedObject setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
```

I have a string called name and i changed the default nsdate "timeStamp" attribute to string "name".

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to delete the App on your device or simulator first, then rebuild & run will solve your issue. As you've modified the model.

**Note**: Every time you've modified the model, you'd better clean the original core data first.

Comment: UNLESS you need users to be able to upgrade from the old model, then implement migration and it'll work.